# Returning default values if MySql query is empty

Tags: mysql

How can i return zero (0) or any other default value if mysql query returns no result? So far i tried with this query which did not work: i am not getting back anything!?

```
SELECT IF( g.value IS NULL, 0,value ) AS goal FROM globals AS g WHERE g.expire_date >= '2018-04-25' ORDER BY g.id DESC
```

Comment: Use IFNULL(g.value,0) if g.value is null, but if there is no result you won´t get anything

Comment: well what i asked is for when i have "no result" so your answer wont work for my case, but thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a LEFT JOIN with a dummy row to ensure that at least one row is returned and then use the suggestion by @nacho to use NULLIF to give you 0 when there are no matches.

e.g.

```
SELECT IFNULL(g.`value`, 0) AS goal
FROM (SELECT 1) AS dummy   
LEFT JOIN `globals` AS g
ON g.`expire_date` >= '2018-04-25';
```